# DVC - Azure Blob Storage - ACR - AKS - Azure Pipeline Integration

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-aks, azure-container-registry, dvc

Has anyone tried 'DVC - Azure Blob Storage - Azure Key Vault - ACR - AKS - Azure Pipeline Integration'. If so, please provide steps or atleast azure-pipeline.yml file.

Expecting steps to achieve above integration or at least azure-pipeline.yml file

Comment: Can you describe your question in more detail? How do you want them to be integrated? What specific functions does each resource perform? What data is stored and what data is transmitted?